# Nginx - How to do two layers of GEO Redirection?

Tags: nginx, centos7, php7

I am trying to redirect visitors based on two conditions, one based on the continent, and then based on their country, here are the current maps that I came up with eventually:

```
## GeoIP Redirection
map $geoip_city_continent_code $closest_server {
  default row.example.com;
  EU      www.example.com;
  NA      us.example.com;
}
map $geoip_city_country_code $closest_server {
  CH      ch.example.com;
}
```

But this did not work, for this I am trying to understand what is the best approach to achieve this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is not related to your issue, but I think is better to redirect the users to the closest server, using geodns, in this way you don't have the tcp handshake, because dns client use udp

Comment: But all the sites are on the same server, how would that work?

Answer (score -1):

For each of those subdomains, add an A record in your DNS configuration with the IP of the server for that region:

```
EU      www.example.com - 1.1.1.2
NA      us.example.com  - 1.1.1.3
```

Comment: But they all hosted on the same server.

Comment: better you add aliases for the same server

Comment: Your answer seems to be illogical, and it make no sense what that has to do with my question!

Comment: Your requirement is multiple dns names pointing to a single IP address.